# Google Compute - CentOS 8 PAM Authentication Fails After Update

Tags: google-compute-engine, pam, centos8

I have a Google Cloud project on which I'm unable to access a CentOS 8 VM. It is running kernel version 4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64 on an x86_64. I'm also running with selinux enabled.

Before running `sudo yum update` on my CentOS 8 VM yesterday, I was able to SSH and authenticate via OTP without issue. Today, all of my OTP codes are failing. I don't know for sure the update was the cause of the issue, but it's the only major change I've made before this issue surfaced.

I've tried resyncing on my phone's Google Authenticator app, which did not help. Further, I've tried each of my emergency scratch codes created at the time of running `google-authenticator`, and none of them have worked either. As far as I can tell, the times are sufficiently in sync between client and server.

As a response to this, I've enabled serial console access, but, at no point that I can recall, I have never set up passwords for my CentOS user--just SSH keys. So, I'm at the point where I can't authenticate via serial console and I can't authenticate via SSH.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Mount the disk to another instance and then check its logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I'd recommend you to check logs. To do it restart your VM instance, if it's possible, and check logs at `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)` for any error or warning messages that could explain what happened to your VM instance.

**To get access via serial console** follow steps below:

1. [Enable serial console connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and check `Enable connecting to serial ports`

2. **Create temporary user and password to login**: shutdown your VM and set a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) by adding at the section **`Custom metadata`** key `startup-script` and value:

   ```
    useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
    echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
   ```

and then start your VM.

3. [Connect to your VM via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> and click on `Connect to serial console`

4. Check what went wrong after update.
5. [Disable access via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=FALSE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and uncheck `Enable connecting to serial ports`

Keep in mind that accordingly  to the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

> **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
> restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
> serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
> instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
> they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
> instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your network
> and specific ports.

In addition, have a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) and 3rd party article [Resolving getting locked out of a Compute Engine](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b).

Comment: Thanks so much for going into so much detail. It seems like the startup script is not getting run (tried two subsequent boots after adding); the console tells me "Login incorrect". The only other thing I can think of is to try mounting disk to another instance, as suggested by @Michael Hampton.

Comment: Thanks, you can find step by step instructions how to mount disk at the documentation Troubleshooting SSH that I mentioned above. Please check and let me know if you were able to fix your issue.

Comment: I was able to mount the disk on a Ubuntu server I had up. I made changes to sshd_config file and the pam.d ssh config file  to temporarily disable PAM authentication. Unfortunately, there now seems to be a permissions issue. When rebooting the server with the disk re-mounted, the serial logs show the machine is unable to read sshd_config, so I'm essentially still locked out. I'm assuming this is an selinux issue, so plan to do more reading.

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution, since the SSH troubleshooting steps are what helped me to move forward. The SELinux issues seemed to be at the heart of my problem--the `~/.google_authenticator` file was also never generated, which I believe is why my OTP rescue codes didn't work.